# Qt/C++ Technique To Show Inline Dialog

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I have QtCreator 5.5 for the Mac, using C++, and I'm new at this. I have a MainForm window. I want to show a dialog inside that but draw it separately in its own UI designer. Then, at runtime, my code will pull that other UI and show it inside that window.

Imagine for instance a main application window. You click a button and you need to see a confirmation dialog. Normally you could do that with a separate window. Instead, I want it to be inline at runtime, to show it like a widget on the main window.

Sure, I could draw my dialog on top my existing window in a widget, but that defeats the point where I want to be able to adjust it in its own designer window, and just load it as necessary in the main window when I need it.

What's the technique in QtCreator and C++ to do this?

Comment: It's called QDialogBox

Comment: @user3528438 QDialog and QMessageBox show a modal window on top the main window. I'm looking for something inline inside the MainWindow, but yet lets me use a separate designer for it. I found the technique on forum.qt.io and I'm going to post it here in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open **QtCreator**. This task can only be done through there.
2. Assuming you have a regular **Qt Widget Application**, you need to just add a **QWidget** control on the **MainWindow's centralWidget** in the **UI Designer**.
3. Next, click **Edit** in the **UI Designer** and then rightclick **Forms**. Choose **Add New...**
4. In the dialog that opens up, choose **Qt** > **Qt Designer Form Class**, and click **Choose...**
5. Select **Widget** and then go with the defaults on the rest. This creates a widget called **Form**, and the `form.h` and `form.cpp` will also be added to your project.
6. Now find the `form.ui` and open it in **Qt Designer**. Add a **Stacked Widget Control** on the QWidget form. Size it to the same size as the parent widget. Next, stick a **Label Control** on the **Stacked Widget Control's** first **page**. This label will be temporary just to prove that this works. You'll set it to the text of "Testing". Now close the designer.
7. Flipping back to your **UI File** of your **Main Window**, find that **QWidget** you added and rightclick it. Choose **Promote...** and a dialog box appears. In that dialog, set **Promoted Class Name** to **Form** and then set **Header File** to `form.h`. Leave everything else on defaults and click **Add** and then **Promote**.
8. You may be expecting to see an immediate change in your **Main Window** in that **QWidget** that you added previously. However, that's not how this works unfortunately. You only see the change at runtime. So, now you should **Run** your application in **Qt Creator**. You'll see when it runs that your widget now contains the contents of that `form.ui` component you created.
9. Now, here's where it gets interesting. You can now draw all your inline modal dialogs on that `form.ui`, just putting them on different **pages** of your **Stacked Widget** control. You can also set the properties of your widget so that the background of the **QWidget** container is opaque and dark (creating a background dimmer) and then, at runtime, resize the **QWidget** to the size of your **Main Window**. When you need to switch to a different dialog, you can use `setCurrentWidget()` or `setCurrentIndex()` on that **StackedWidget** item like so:

```
QStackedWidget *w = ui->widget->findChild<QStackedWidget *>("stackedWidget");
w->setCurrentIndex(1);
```

In that example, I had a **QWidget** control on my **MainWindow** named simply `widget`. I then found the control on it called `stackedWidget`. Once I had it, I used the `setCurrentIndex(x)` method on it to change the page of that widget to show the one I needed. Remember that this is a zero-based index. So, `(1)` would be page 2.

Answer (score 0):

[QMainWindow::setCentralWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget)

Inside your QMainWindow constructor add:

```
MyDialogClass myDialog = new MyDialogClass();
setCentralWidget(myDialog);
```